# malloc-ating multidimensional array in function

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, malloc

I'm trying to allocate a 2d array in a C program. It works fine in the main function like this (as explained [here](http://www.eumus.edu.uy/eme/c/c-notes_summit/intermediate/sx9.html)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int ** grid;
    int i, nrows=10, ncols=10;
    grid = malloc( sizeof(int *) * nrows);

    if (grid == NULL){
        printf("ERROR: out of memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i=0;i<nrows;i++){
        grid[i] = malloc( sizeof(int) * ncols);
        if (grid[i] == NULL){
            printf("ERROR: out of memory\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("Allocated!\n");

    grid[5][6] = 15;
    printf("%d\n", grid[5][6]);
    return 0;
}
```

But since I have to do this several times with different arrays, I was trying to move the code into a separate function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int malloc2d(int ** grid, int nrows, int ncols){
    int i;
    grid = malloc( sizeof(int *) * nrows);

    if (grid == NULL){
        printf("ERROR: out of memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i=0;i<nrows;i++){
        grid[i] = malloc( sizeof(int) * ncols);
        if (grid[i] == NULL){
            printf("ERROR: out of memory\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("Allocated!\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int ** grid;

    malloc2d(grid, 10, 10);
    grid[5][6] = 15;
    printf("%d\n", grid[5][6]);
    return 0;
}
```

However, although it doesn't complain while allocating, I get segmentation fault when accessing the array. I read different posts on decayed arrays and similar topics, but I still can't figure out how to solve this problem. I imagine I'm not passing the 2d array correctly to the function.

Many thanks.

Comment: Generally, when you run out of memory, you should call the `exit` function. Best is to make a function that does that for you, say, `xmalloc`.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's usually a lot easier to avoid dynamically allocating multidimensional arrays; since multiple blocks have to be allocated it is less efficient than making a single allocation and doing the pointer arithmetic yourself.  The code required to manage (allocate, reallocate, and deallocate) multidimensional arrays is also significantly more complex.

Comment: @James: Actually, in C it's impossible to allocate a multidimensional array. Multidimensional arrays *are* single memory blocks, with the multiplication to find the right location done as syntactic sugar done by the compiler to make it easier. (In C++ you actually can do this.... i.e. `new int[5][6]` ... I think, but I could be wrong there, in which case you can't do it in C++ either)

Comment: @Billy Yes, `new int[5][6]` works in C++, but I don't know how to write the `int.... = new int[5][5]` part. I have gotten as far as `int* b[5] = new int[5][5];` but that gives the compiler error `cannot convert from 'int (*)[5]' to 'int *[5]'`. Tell me if you figure it out, I didn't know you could do this.

Comment: @Seth: You could always use `auto`. :)

Comment: @Billy yeah, but I don't think `new int[5][5];` is unusable without `auto`. It'd be nice to know what it actually is.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: Agreed, but I don't know. Never had a reason to dynamically allocate anything like that; when that happens I'd be using `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: @Billy:  To rephrase what I said:  it's usually a lot easier to avoid dynamically allocating structures that can be used as if they were multidimensional arrays (i.e., structures consisting of arrays of pointers to arrays).

Comment: @Seth:  `int (*b)[5] = new int[5][5];`

Comment: @Billy:  Also, I don't see why you can't treat a dynamically allocated block as a multidimensional array, e.g. `int (*b)[5] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5 * 5);`  You have to know at least N - 1 of the dimensions at compile-time, but that is a general restriction when working with arrays in C and C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is not a multidimensional array; it is a single dimensional array containing pointers to single dimensional arrays. Multidimensional arrays do not contain pointers; they are single memory blocks.

Your problem here is that you have a pointer to a pointer, and you're trying to return it from your function through a parameter. If you're going to do that, you're going to need a pointer to a pointer to a pointer as your parameter, and you're going to have to pass the address of a pointer to a pointer to the method. If you don't do this, you're not changing the value of the variable `grid` in `main` -- you're changing the one which was copied as the parameter to the `malloc2d` function. Because the `grid` in `main` is left uninitialized, you get a undefined behavior.

Here's an example of what I mean as the fix:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int malloc2d(int *** grid, int nrows, int ncols){
    int i;
    *grid = malloc( sizeof(int *) * nrows);

    if (*grid == NULL){
        printf("ERROR: out of memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i=0;i<nrows;i++){
        (*grid)[i] = malloc( sizeof(int) * ncols);
        if ((*grid)[i] == NULL){
            printf("ERROR: out of memory\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("Allocated!\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int ** grid;

    malloc2d(&grid, 10, 10);
    grid[5][6] = 15;
    printf("%d\n", grid[5][6]);
    return 0;
}
```

Additional notes:

- If a single allocation fails, you leak the allocation for the first array, as well as the allocations for all previous rows. You need to call `free` on those before returning.
- You're returning through a parameter, even though you really don't have to. If I were writing this, I'd make the method return `int **`, and signal error by returning `0`.

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic answer! I changed the function to return `int **` as you also suggested.

Comment: `(*grid)` I didn't know that it can be used like that. It solved my problem too. Because I want to pass **A to a funcion and inside that function will know my size (cols and rows) and then write the information inside that function. then outside I want to refer to its values. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your function, fixed:

```
int malloc2d(int *** grid, int nrows, int ncols){
    int i;
    *grid = (int**)malloc( sizeof(int *) * nrows);

    if (*grid == NULL){
        printf("ERROR: out of memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i=0;i<nrows;i++){

        (*grid)[i] = (int*)malloc( sizeof(int) * ncols);
        if ((*grid)[i] == NULL){
            printf("ERROR: out of memory\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("Allocated!\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int ** grid;

    malloc2d(&grid, 10, 10);
    grid[5][6] = 15;
    printf("%d\n", grid[5][6]);
    return 0;
}
```

Note the function now recieves an `int***` and you pass the *address* of your `int**` to the function. The function then dereferences the `int***` to put the address of the allocated memory block in it.

Comment: That's not fixed. The `if (grid == NULL){` and `if (grid[i] == NULL){` lines also need fixed.

Comment: @Billy whoops, missed that. Fixed.

Comment: @Billy thanks, though your answer is more thorough and complete, and deserves the green check. +1 for your answer. Hopefully the asker will return and select it.

Answer (score 2):

**C** is pass by value. And to sum up the error you are doing, this example should be helpful -

```
void foo( int *temp )
{
     temp = malloc(sizeof(int)) ;
     // temp is assigned to point to new location but the actual variable
     // passed from main do not point to the location temp is pointing to.

     *temp = 10 ;
}

int main()
{
     int *ptr ;
     foo( ptr ) ;

     // ptr is still unintialized
     *ptr = 5 ; // Segmentation fault or Undefined behavior

     return 0;
}
```

So, instead you should do -

```
void foo( int **temp )
{
    *temp = malloc(sizeof (int) );
    // ...
}
```

And now call the function as `foo(&ptr);` in the `main()` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want `malloc2d` to return a status code, the parameter needs to be of type `int***`:

```
int malloc2d(int *** grid, int nrows, int ncols){
```

And you need to use `*grid` to refer to the supplied buffer:

```
    int i;
    *grid = malloc( sizeof(int *) * nrows);

    if (*grid == NULL){
        printf("ERROR: out of memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i=0;i<nrows;i++){
        (*grid)[i] = malloc( sizeof(int) * ncols);
        if ((*grid)[i] == NULL){
            printf("ERROR: out of memory\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("Allocated!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Then, when calling `malloc2d`, pass it the address of an `int**` to fill in:

```
int ** grid;

malloc2d(&grid, 10, 10);
```

Comment: I think you have one too many `*`s on your second to last `int****` -- it should only be 3 `*`s.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: No, for `int** grid`, `&&grid` was of type `int****`.

Comment: @John: Ah.. where did `&&grid` come from? It's not in the OP's code.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: No idea. I probably mistyped it myself! Fixed, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

C is actually always pass by value, so when you pass in 'grid' you are passing in a value and the function is modifying its own local copy.  Try passing in '&grid' instead and modify malloc2d appropriately.

Comment: The problem is larger than just adding the `&`. First of all, the compiler won't allow it due to the wrong level of indirection, and second, the function is still wrong after you do it.

Answer (score 0):

That's not your about your segmentation fault problem, but you should really consider to use a single malloc call to allocate all necessary memory space need by grid.

```
grid = malloc (nrows * ncols * sizeof(int *))
```

Look at Bill ONeary answer regarding pointer of pointer of pointer.

Comment: While I agree with this, it really doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @Billy Oneal: you are right but he is too much complicating the code instead of using a simple solution.

Comment: I agree, but you have not posted an answer to the OP's question. This content reallly belongs in a comment if it's not going to answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter should be below, with free (!) and initialized values for each grid element:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NROWS 10
#define NCOLS 10

int main()
{
    int (* grid)[NCOLS] = calloc(NROWS,sizeof*grid);

    /* no more needed here malloc2d(grid, 10, 10); */
    grid[5][6] = 15;
    printf("%d\n", grid[5][6]);
    free(grid); /* every c/malloc need a free */
    return 0;
}
```