# need help in understanding passing char* [] to function

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am trying to pass a array of pointers to string to a function where I need to set the values. In the passing function I do not know the number of strings I will get, the called function is calling some other function which returns list of strings.

Sample code below:

```
int main() {
    char** list;
    create(list);
}

int create(char **array) {

    char* str[] = { "hello", "dear" };
    int len;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        len = strlen(str[i]);
        printf("%d\n", len);
        *(array + i) = (char*) malloc(len * sizeof(char*));
        strcpy(*(array + i), str[i]);
        i++;

    }
    return 1;
}
```

This gives me segmentation fault.

What wrong am I doing here. Please help.

Thanks

**EDIT**
Updated code from below comments:

```
int main() {
    char** list;
    create(list);
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        printf("%s\n", list[i]); // segmentation fault
    }
}

int create(char **array) {

    char* str[] = { "hello", "dear" };
    int len;
    int i = 0;
    array = malloc(2 * sizeof(char*));
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        len = strlen(str[i]);
        printf("%d\n", len);
        *(array + i) = (char*) malloc(len * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(*(array + i), str[i]);
        printf("%s\n", array[i]); // this prints
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Now getting segmentation fault in main while printing the list.

**Actual code where I am reading the strings**

```
int i;
for ( i=0; i<reply->elements; i++ )
{
printf( "Result: %d---%s\n", i,reply->element[i]->str );
*array[i] = (char*)malloc(strlen(reply->element[i]->str));
printf("***");
strcpy(array[i],reply->element[i]->str);
printf( "Array[%d]: %s\n", i,array[i] );
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [malloc-ating multidimensional array in function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845686/malloc-ating-multidimensional-array-in-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly alloc memory for the individual strings, but fail to alloc some for the array itself.

You should use:

```
int main() {
    char* list[8] = {0}; /* initialize pointers to NULL */
    create(list);

    /* free allocated memory - free(NULL) is legal and is a noop */
    for (i=0; i<sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]); i++) free(list[i]);
    return 0;  /* never return random value from main */
}
```

And you should remove the `i++` at the end of the loop in function create because it leads to a double increment.

Alternatively you could alloc the array itself in the function `create`:

```
int create(char ***array) {

    char* str[] = { "hello", "dear" };
    int len;
    int i = 0;
    *array = malloc(1 + sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0]));
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        len = strlen(str[i]) + 1;
        printf("%d\n", len);
        (*array)[i] = malloc(len * sizeof(char*));
        strcpy((*array)[i], str[i]);
    }
    (*array)[i] = NULL;
    return i;
}

int main() {
    char** list;
    create(&list);
}
```

In above code, the length of the array is the return value from `create`, and the last element of list is a NULL (in the same logic as argc/argv).

Comment: Thanks. I do not know the size in main so I have to allocate in create(). I did that and now create is fine but when I try to print values in main it gives seg fault.

Comment: Thanks. This works. But what' wrong with the edited code I posted and what is the use of **(*array)[i] = NULL;**

Comment: OK. Got it. It's the null terminator for the array. Correct?

Comment: @Jardanian: As I said, I wanted the array to be terminated with a NULL pointer, as is the argv array. But this is absolutely optional since the length is already passed in return value.

Comment: @Jardanian: In your code, you just pass `list` to the function. So when you assign the malloced memory to it, you just change **a local copy** and not the caller variable. That's the reason why I pass the address of `list`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. May I request you to please explain just two things.
1.) How will we write (*array)[i] as just pointer notation, is it **(array+i)?
2.) What did I pass as char **, I thought this passes the address to first location.

Comment: Ok. If I had created like **char *a[2]** and passed **create(a)** then would it be the address or still I require to do **create(&a)**. Sorry, but I am trying to understand the pointers but getting lost always.

Comment: @Jardanian: C always pass by value. So you can *use* what was passed but not *change* it. If you define `char *a[2]` and then pass `create(a)`, you can **use** `a` in `a[i] = ...`, but you must never have `a = ...` in a function `create(... a)`.

Comment: Thanks. Some say pass by ref and some say pass by val. I'll read more but how this happens [change value of char array in called function](https://ideone.com/NVS5nu)

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to allocate some space for `list` or undefined behavior occurs:

   ```
   char* list[2];
   ```
2. You increment `i` twice; therefore, remove the `i++` from the bottom of the `for` loop.

---

Minor notes:

- refer to string literals as `const char*`
- use `array[i]` instead of `*(array + i)`
- [don't cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
- `malloc` allocates too much space as you allocate `len` `char*`s, even though you need just `char`s. Also, as @CoolGuy noted, you need one extra byte for the null byte. Replace the allocation with

  ```
  array[i] = malloc(len * sizeof(char) + sizeof(char));
  ```

  or

  ```
  array[i] = malloc(len + 1);
  ```
- call `free` after `malloc`
- you assign `0` twice to `i`;  remove the initialization

Comment: Thanks. I do not know the size in main so cannot give it there. I get what you are saying about passing pointer but is not pointer what I am passing? I understand that I am passing address to first location.

Comment: @Jardanian Why don't you know the size? Viewing your code it seems you do know it as the `for` loop will definitely loop twice.

Comment: This is just a sample code which I prepared to show what I need. Actual code is bigger.

Comment: You forgot to allocate space for the NUL-terminator.

Comment: From the calling function I'll pass the list and an pointer to integer which will be updated with the size.

Comment: @Jardanian Then I recommend posting the real code. How exactly do you read the strings? This is important as it's tightly related to how to determine the number of strings.

Answer (score 0):

You allocate two arrays (`char*`) to store the strings "hello" and "dear" but does not allocate the array (`char**`) containing those two string array.

Comment: Thanks. **array = malloc(2*sizeof(char*));** this is what I did in create now. Is it correct.

Comment: @LeFlou  You forgot  space  for `Null character` in `malloc` . It can cause **UB**.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to change declaration of function `create` to this -

```
int create(char ***array);
```

And call it like this -

```
create(&list);
```

In function `create` allocate memory like this -

```
    *array = malloc(2 * sizeof(char*));
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
        {
            len = strlen(str[i]);
            printf("%d\n", len);
            (*array)[i] =malloc(len * sizeof(char*)+1);
            strcpy((*array)[i], str[i]);
        }
```

And do the printing as you do in `main`.

Note - `free` memory that you allocate.

And you should declare `len` as type `size_t`  **->** `size_t len;` 
and print it with `%zu` specifier in `printf` .

See working code here -https://ideone.com/GX2k9T